# accessible longest match (from the beginning) without substring in replacement

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i wondered if it is possible using `sed` to match the longest string (from the beginning) NOT containing a substring making any match accessible laterwards using sed's regex replacement variables `\n`.

regarding the following snippet

```
echo "blabla/a/b/dee/per" | sed -r -e 's:([^/a]*):\1:g'
```

i am trying to print out the longest match containing any sign indicated by `*` but not including the substring `/a` in a way the above snippet prints out

```
blabla
```

regarding (`/a` deleted/replaced)

```
echo "blabla/b/b/dee/per" | sed -r -e 's:([^/a]*):\1:g'
```

i am expecting

```
blabla/b/b/dee/per
```

as output due to substring `/a` is not available so and the longest match leads up to the strings end. i am stuck at describing the substring `/a`.

**CAUTION:** `[^/a]` is just a placeholder to describe the problem. it needs imo to be replaced with a correct substring description.
is that possible in some way using sed?

thank you in advance

**EDIT:** John1024's third answer completes this question. the following snippet is now used:

```
 sed -r -e 's:(/a|$):\x00:;s:^(.*)\x00(.*):\1:g'
```

**EDIT:** to fulfill my original task to prepend values to pathes with different prefixes containing a substring surrounded by other characters i finally came along with

```
 $ echo -ne "blabla/a/b/dee/per\nblabla/b/dee/per" | \
   sed -r -e 's:(.*)/a/b:\1\x00:;s:(.*)/b:\1\x01:;s:^(.*)\x00(.*):\1/foo/a/b\2:g;s:^(.*)\x01(.*):\1/foo/b\2:g'
 blabla/foo/a/b/dee/per
 blabla/foo/b/dee/per
```

which first replaces prefix pathes `/a/b` or `/b` with `\x00` or `\x01` respectively making the sed groups, a.k.a. prefix and suffix pathes, accessible through `\n` like described below.

**NOTE:** additional trick used here to avoid `(.*)/b` matching `(.*)/a/b`
too is to replace longest path prefixes first.
thanks again @John1024

Comment: In your first example, isn't `/b/dee/per` longer than `blabla` and therefore the correct answer?

Comment: longest match (from the beginning) without including the substring then. i thought sed just handles `(.*)` as longest match from bthe beginning of a line.

Comment: sed is a unix thing. I don't know sed, but I know that `s{([^/a]*)}{\1}g` doesn't replace anything. `[^\/a]` as far as I know is a character class, i.e. not a substring.

Comment: yep @sin that is the `.` :) i dont know how to transform the character class into a matching substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find string from beginning until first occurrence of `/a` (2nd version of question)

```
$ echo "blabla/a/b/dee/per" | sed 's|/a.*||'
blabla

$ echo "blabla/b/b/dee/per" | sed 's|/a.*||'
blabla/b/b/dee/per
```

### Find longest string not containing `/a` (Original Question)

This problem is a more natural match to awk:

```
$ echo "blabla/a/b/dee/per" | awk -v RS='/a' 'length($0)>max{longest=$0; max=length(longest);} END{print longest;}'
/b/dee/per

$ echo "blabla/b/b/dee/per" | awk -v RS='/a' 'length($0)>max{longest=$0; max=length(longest);} END{print longest;}'
blabla/b/b/dee/per
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='/a'`

  This sets the record separator to `/a`.  This divides the input upon every occurrence of `/a`.
- `length($0)>max{longest=$0; max=length(longest);}`

  If the current record, `$0`, is longer than the previous longest record, update `longest` and `max` with the new record.
- `END{print longest;}`

  When we reach the end of the input, print out the `longest` record that we saw.

### Capture string from beginning up to the first `/a` in a sed group (3rd version of question)

```
$ echo "blabla/a/b/dee/per" | sed -r 's!(/a|$)!\x00!; s|^(.*)\x00.*|I found "\1".|'
I found "blabla".

$ echo "blabla/b/b/dee/per" | sed -r 's!(/a|$)!\x00!; s|^(.*)\x00.*|I found "\1".|'
I found "blabla/b/b/dee/per".
```

How it works:

- `s!(/a|$)!\x00!`

  This replaces the first occurrence of `/a` with the NUL character, `\x00`.  If no occurrence of `/a` is found, then the NUL character is placed at the end of the string (signified in a regex by `$`).  (The NUL character was chosen because it can never be held in a bash variable and, thus, is extremely unlikely to be in an input string.)
- `s|^(.*)\x00.*|I found "\1".|`

  This saves group 1 all the characters up to the location where the first `/a` used to be.  We can use `\1` in the replacement as we please.

As written, this requires a sed, such as GNU sed, which supports the NUL-character, hex 00.  If your sed does not support NUL, then replace the `\x00` with some character that won't be in your input string but that your sed does support.  `\x01` might be a good second choice.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i really need `blabla` to be printed after replacing a sed compatible description for a substring which is currently `[^/a]` but not working as expected.

Comment: Does the revised answer not meet your needs?  By the way, `[^/a]`  matches any characters are neither  `/` nor `a`.  That seems unrelated to what you ask for in the text.  It has nothing to do with a `/` preceding an `a`.

Comment: hey your edit just looks fine. i probably need to adjust the title. could you perhaps give some additional explanation on the sed command which just fit my needs? and yes the snippet contains the wrong usage of the character class because i was not able to figure out how to describe `not containing substring`. thank you

Comment: argh. it just replaces the the end of the string with nothing. but i need to access the match `blabla` laterwards thats why i just used `-r` and `\1` surrounding the "match up to first occurence" with brackets. additinally that's the reason why i am trying to find "the longest match from the beginning not containing a substring" any suggestions on how to deal with that?

Comment: @EmilKakkau See the new section I added at the end of the answer.

Comment: awesome. sry i can't vote multiple times for all of your answers :) the third version helps me a lot, told me something unknown and is therefor selected as the right answer. thank you very much.